# JSON not renderring in IE

Tags: html, json, google-chrome, internet-explorer, iis

Ok, I'm running 2 web servers. On each of these servers, I have the same web page, which uses some JSON to render data. Let's call them servers A & B.

When accessing the page on server A, everything renders correctly in both IE and Chrome.

When accessing the page on server B, Chrome renders correctly, but IE does not seem to process the JSON.

All files on both servers are IDENTICAL. I have no idea what would cause something like this.

Comment: Have you looked in the IE Developer Tools for any issues?

Comment: Yes, nothing is really throwing any alarms.

Comment: It obviously HAS to be something on that web server, so what would cause it to render JSON in Chrome but not IE?

Comment: The browser downloads the webpage and associated assets from the server and then renders these. Within Developer Tools you can go to the Network tab, enable Network Traffic Capturing and then refresh the page. Check if all assets are being successfully returned including the JSON.

Comment: Check the HTTP response headers on servers A and B for differences.